# Postgres with timescale extension does not use skip scan in DISTINCT query

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, timescaledb

I want my query to use skip scan and followed this post:
https://www.timescale.com/blog/how-we-made-distinct-queries-up-to-8000x-faster-on-postgresql/

Skip scan should be available from timescale version 2.2.1 onwards. I am using 2.3.1.

For this I generated a new index as described in the post (`psr_type_tzc_timestampidx`)
[image]

If I run this query

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE SELECT DISTINCT ON (psr_type) psr_type, utc_timestamp
   FROM generation_per_type
   ORDER BY psr_type, utc_timestamp DESC
```

the query plan looks like this:

```
Unique  (cost=126.37..2781479.65 rows=20 width=12) (actual time=2114.861..21926.310 rows=20 loops=1)
  ->  Merge Append  (cost=126.37..2678236.07 rows=41297430 width=12) (actual time=2114.858..18887.986 rows=41297430 loops=1)
        Sort Key: _hyper_2_279_chunk.psr_type, _hyper_2_279_chunk.utc_timestamp DESC
        ->  Index Only Scan using _hyper_2_279_chunk_psr_type_ztc_timestampidx on _hyper_2_279_chunk  (cost=0.42..1651.47 rows=85650 width=12) (actual time=11.596..36.191 rows=85650 loops=1)
              Heap Fetches: 0
        ->  Index Only Scan using _hyper_2_280_chunk_psr_type_ztc_timestampidx on _hyper_2_280_chunk  (cost=0.42..2881.85 rows=149635 width=12) (actual time=15.261..59.023 rows=149635 loops=1)
              Heap Fetches: 0
        ->  Index Only Scan using _hyper_2_281_chunk_psr_type_ztc_timestampidx on _hyper_2_281_chunk  (cost=0.42..2889.45 rows=150069 width=12) (actual time=15.068..57.579 rows=150069 loops=1)
              Heap Fetches: 0
        ->  Index Only Scan using _hyper_2_282_chunk_psr_type_ztc_timestampidx on _hyper_2_282_chunk  (cost=0.42..2891.31 rows=150119 width=12) (actual time=14.395..67.302 rows=150119 loops=1)
              Heap Fetches: 0
        ->  Index Only Scan using _hyper_2_283_chunk_psr_type_ztc_timestampidx on _hyper_2_283_chunk  (cost=0.42..2891.56 rows=150136 width=12) (actual time=19.602..70.908 rows=150136 loops=1)
              Heap Fetches: 0
        ->  Index Only Scan using _hyper_2_284_chunk_psr_type_ztc_timestampidx on _hyper_2_284_chunk  (cost=0.42..2888.48 rows=150004 width=12) (actual time=16.743..63.102 rows=150004 loops=1)
              Heap Fetches: 0
        ->  Index Only Scan using _hyper_2_285_chunk_psr_type_ztc_timestampidx on _hyper_2_285_chunk  (cost=0.42..2892.36 rows=150189 width=12) (actual time=15.833..62.003 rows=150189 loops=1)
```

No sign of something like `Custom Scan (SkipScan) on _hyper_8_79_chunk`.
What are possible reasons why skip scan has not been used for this query? And any idea what I could try to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a cost analysis and it might choose to not use skipscan if the number of unique values is close to the number of total rows.

The other possibility is that you are using the Apache 2.0 licensed version of TimescaleDB in which case skipscan isn't available.

If neither of these factors apply I wonder if you might be able to get a reproducible case to share with the team as an issue?
Hope this helps? *Transparency: I work for Timescale*

Comment: Thanks for answering! I used `DISTINCT ON` like in the example in the blog post. 
`SELECT DISTINCT ON (tags_id) tags_id, time FROM cpu`
`ORDER BY tags_id, time DESC`
`LIMIT 10 OFFSET 50;`

As I understand it the distinct is only on one column but one can select more than one. 
So I think this should not be the problem but I might be wrong. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: Ah darn you are right, I read that query incorrectly my apologies. I'll check with our team if we have any other suggestions beyond the data distribution one.

Comment: OK, checked in and updated the response accordingly

Comment: We are using the Docker Image from here https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb-docker. I am afraid it is the Apache 2.0 version and therefore skip scan is not working. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should be able to use the full edition if you are self-hosting? There's a directory in the stack `/tsl` and the code is available when you 'install' the TSL license. There may be a few things to unpack here... 


* You might find the -ha docker image better in general (you don't have to use it with multi-node) https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb-docker-ha 
* It could be that you need to finish the install check `select * from pg_available_extensions ORDER BY name DESC;` and you could also verify with `\dx` to see if things are as expected.

Comment: If you are able to hop into Slack or the Timescale forum we should be able to help you out.

Comment: With the timescaledb-docker-ha docker image it works as in the example :)

Comment: Yay! I think what maybe happened is that the TLS code is somehow inactive in the single Docker image. Thanks for letting me know as I'll know where to point developers next time. Win all round :)